# Probability of the random variable is chosen from first distribution

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

Suppose there are two normal random distribution:
$$
a\sim N(0,9) \quad b\sim N(0, 16)
$$

Person Alice randomly chooses a distribution from $a$ and $b$ with equal probability (50%) and then draw a number from that distribution.

Alice shows Bob this number and Bob observes the value $2$.

What is the probability that this number is from distribution $a$?

Comment: My guess: the relative probabilities are proportional to the density functions at $x=2$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

$P\{pick \  2\} = P\{pick \ 2 \ | choose \ a\}\cdot P\{choose \ a\} + P\{pick \ 2 \ | choose \ b\}\cdot P\{choose \ b\} = \frac{1}{2}\cdot f_{a}(2)+ \frac{1}{2}\cdot  f_{b}(2)$

where $f_{a}(2)$ is the pdf of $a\sim N(0,9)$ and $f_{b}(2)$ is the pdf of $b\sim N(0, 16)$

Comment: But I do not think that PDF is the probability.